# How to order values from SQL in drop down aphabeticallty and place the value "Other" at the bottom

Tags: php, sql, drop-down-menu

I have somewhat simple question but I am unable to figure it out myself.

In my PHP file I order the values from SQL alphabetically using the following command:

```
$qry_makes  = "SELECT * FROM ".$tblprefix."makes Where type ='1' and status ='1' ORDER BY title ASC";
```

This arranges the values alphabetically, which is what I want. The problem is that this places the value "Other" in the middle of the dropdown and I want to place it at the bottom. I did some research I found that I can use this:

```
order by
case when value= 'Other' then 1 else 0 end,
value
```

I tried to play with this code and embed it in mine but I am missing something.

Any help will be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: What do you mean you are missing something?And value shoudnt be title?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN value= 'Other' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, title ASC
```

Comment: Although I think `value` should be `title` - ? (I copied that from yours)

Comment: Yes value should be title, thanks for the answer, works great!

Answer (score 3):

Other should not be in your database.

you can just write

```
<option name="Other">Other</option>
```

at the end, after all your SQL entries.

Comment: I share this opinion. It's indeed good practice to only have explicit options in your database and not 'general' options, like other for instance.